# Create Docker Container from Command Fails, but Docker Desktop Succeeds

Tags: windows, docker

## Problem

When I run the following commands the container fails to run

```
docker container create --name Test1 --env Var1=Val1 --env Var2=Val2 image-name:v1.0
docker start Test1
```

However, when I create it from Docker Desktop, it works perfectly fine.

I would like to automate some creation of containers, but commands do not appear to behave the same as running from Docker Desktop.

Is Docker Desktop including any additional arguments when creating the container that I would need to include in my command?

## Additional Information

I am running a Windows Container on a Windows Computer and running the command in PowerShell.
I have also tried running the command in Command Prompt, but no luck.

Comment: When you say "it fails to run", what does happen?  What's in the Dockerfile for the `image-name:v1.0` image?  The separate `docker create; docker start` sequence is a little unusual, if you `docker run` the container in the foreground with the same options, do you get more information?

Comment: It says
`Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]`
`(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.`

And then exits.

When I check in Docker Desktop it says Exited(0)

Comment: That sounds like it works?

Comment: It created it successfully, but it stops almost immediately. And when I restart it, it stops immediately again.

Comment: When creating it in Docker Desktop, it keeps running. I don't understand what the difference is.